# Is there a way to add a string character to the values in a column in periods?

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe called "time_df" which has one column "tstamps" which is consists of string values.I need to add a "0" to row 0,5,10,.... till the end of the dataframe.

[snapshot of time_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZkNR.png)

Is there a function/method to accomplish this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.ljust`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.ljust.html):

Consider below `df`:

```
In [1883]: df = pd.DataFrame({'tstamps':['1606.9104', '1606.91046', '1606.9107']})

In [1884]: df
Out[1884]: 
      tstamps
0   1606.9104
1  1606.91046
2   1606.9107
```

Now, you have to make all rows `length` to `10` by adding `0` to the right wherever missing.

```
In [1889]: df['tstamps'] = df['tstamps'].str.ljust(10, '0')

In [1890]: df
Out[1890]: 
      tstamps
0  1606.91040
1  1606.91046
2  1606.91070
```